# iPhone simulator crashing on startup

Tags: iphone, xcode

Okay, so my Xcode and iPhone simulator have become really screwed up lately, all i remember doing right before this started happening is i turned off my mac. So, my first problem is that every time i open up iPhone simulator, it says the simulated application can't be run and asks to switch sdk and i click 5.0 and it keeps on saying that. I have tried reinstalling Xcode 3 times now. Second, whenever i go to open up the MainStoryboard.iphone/ipad files, Xcode freezes up and gives me the option to either crash or continue in a poor state or something like that. Next, the app I'm trying to create used to work, but then all of a sudden, it would crash at startup with this error message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in:/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Sym/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-01-03 21:02:45.802 ibtoold[1399:d03] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-933/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:179

Details:  Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" (1402) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5. Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.
Function: NSDistantObject<IBCocoaTouchToolProtocol> *IBAttachToCocoaTouchTool(IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
```

That is the error that i got when beginning to run the app, now instead, it just gives me two errors while building the app and here is what those say:

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
Verify exit code of build task 'CompileStoryboard MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard'
Build task failed without generating error messages.
```

These have to be in some way related and it has either to do with the storyboard settings or the iOS simulator, this has been a huge setback for the making of my app, if anyone has had this issue, please help

EDIT: ok have been trying to see if this same thing happens on other projects and it seems to be only that app with the errors, but IOS simulator doesn't work for anything. Also, literally every other thing i try to do on Xcode now prompts a crash, even trying to open up a project and look at errors in new window.

Answer (score 0):

Update to a newer version of Xcode, they run smoother and are a lot less buggy.